# Rails - render :layout => false on new action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using `render :layout => false` for my new action.

All works fine, until I submit the form with validation errors. The create action calls `render :new` and I see the form, with the bullets outlining the errors. The issue is that the form now renders with application layout and seems to be ignoring the `render :layout => false`.

From what I can tell I believe this is because I am not actually redirecting to :new, just rendering the :new view whilst still in the create action. I cant add `render :layout => false` to the create action, because rails only allows one render per action.

Is there a way to get the form with validation errors to not use the application layout? I still want the bullets with the validation errors.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, looks like I worked this out. Thought I had tried this but must have been a syntax error before.

The solution is to add `render :new, :layout => false` to your create action.

Answer (score -1):

Iam not sure, but you can use a

```
layout :false, only: [:create]
```

hope this may help.